# Disintegration and marginal

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, marginal-distribution, pushforward

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Let $\gamma \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)$, where $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is the subset of the probability measures $\pi$ such that
$$
\pi (A\times Y) =\mu(a) \text{  and  } \pi(X\times B)=\nu(B)
$$
Disintegrating $\gamma$ according to $(h, h_{\#} \gamma$), I get a family of measures $\gamma_{y}$ concentrated on $h^{-1}(\{y\})$.

Can I say something about the marginals of $\gamma_{y}$?

Answer (score 0):

I found something, not exactly what I need, maybe it could be a good start.

If $\gamma = \gamma_{y} \oplus \alpha_{\#} \gamma$ the disintegration of $\gamma$ according to $(\alpha, \alpha_{\#})$.
Then $\beta_{\#}\gamma = \beta_{\#} \gamma_{y} \oplus \alpha_{\#} \gamma$

Now let $ \beta_{\#}\gamma = \mu_{y} \oplus \delta_{\#} \beta_{\#}\gamma$ the disintegration of $\beta_{\#} \gamma$ according to $(\delta, \delta_{\#} \beta_{\#} \gamma)$ then

$$
 \mu_{y} = \beta_{\#} \gamma_{y}
$$